# Android back button not working with navigators inside tabs on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, tabs, navigation

I need a navigator inside each tab, so when I push a new Widget, the tab bar keeps on screen. The Code is working very well, but the android back button is closing the app instead of running Navigator.pop()

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabBarDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 1,
        child: Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: const BottomAppBar(
            color: Colors.black,
            child: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Navigator(
                onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
                  return MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => newPage()))),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class newPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const newPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("new page"),
      ),
      body: Center(child: Icon(Icons.add)),
    );
  }
}
```

the code is also available [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=93ffb0904206fd23df620f5a6f030b6c) but on dartpad you cannot test the android back button.

Comment: in my tests it's as if the new navigator, inside the tab, wasn't "overlapping" the root navigator from MaterialApp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should create a key for your navigator

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> homeNavigatorKey = GlobalKey();
```

then add this key to your navigator

```
Navigator(
      key: homeNavigatorKey,
```

then wrap your `Navigator` in a `WillPopScope` widget and add the `onWillPop` as follows

```
child: WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
      return !(await homeNavigatorKey.currentState!.maybePop());
    },
    child: Navigator(
      key: homeNavigatorKey,
```

this will check if the `navigatorKey` can pop a route or not, if yes it will pop this route only if no it will pop itself thus closing the app

Answer (score 0):

Based on omar hatem's answer

In the TabBarController State:

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> screenANavigatorKey = GlobalKey();
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> screenBNavigatorKey = GlobalKey();
```

Helper function:

```
GlobalKey<NavigatorState> indexToNavigatorKey(int index) {
  switch (index) {
    case 0: return screenANavigatorKey;
    case 1: return screenBNavigatorKey;
  }
}
```

In the `WillPopScope.onWillPop`:

```
// I am saving the current screen index in some variable
GlobalKey<NavigatorState> subScreenNavigatorKey = indexToNavigatorKey(currentScreen);
await subScreenNavigatorKey.currentState?.maybePop();
return ...
```

Child of the `WillPopScope`:

```
CupertinoTabScaffold(
  controller: _controller,
  tabBuilder: (context, index) =>
    CupertinoTabView(
      navigatorKey: screenToNavigatorKey(index),
      builder: (context) => // your current screen goes here
```