# Back button isn't working as expected in flutter's tab navigation setup

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-navigation

I have a bottom navigation bar in my flutter application that contains multiple tabs. In this app, I am primarily facing 2 issues:

1. If I press the android back button on the home page of any of the tabs, I am navigated back to my phone's home screen, I expect to be taken to the last tab. I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70645881/android-back-button-not-working-with-navigators-inside-tabs-on-flutter) question but they are using the maybePop() method on State inside the onWillPop function of the WillPopScope widget which is giving me an error.
   This is the widget handling tab navigation:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int currentPage = 0;
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> mainKey = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> settingsKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              buildOffstatgeNavigator(0, mainKey),
              buildOffstatgeNavigator(1, settingsKey),
            ],
          ),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xff262647),
          bottomNavigationBar: GNav(
            tabBorderRadius: 25,
            gap: 5, // the tab button gap between icon and text
            color: const Color(0xff9A9A9A),
            // activeColor: const Color.fromARGB(
                // 255, 47, 15, 83), // selected icon and text color
            activeColor: const Color(0xff472C69),
            tabBackgroundColor: const Color(0xffBA99FF)
                .withOpacity(0.9), // selected tab background color
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 12, vertical: 15), // navigation bar padding

            tabs: const [
              GButton(
                icon: TimeTypeIcons.home,
                text: "Home",
              ),
              GButton(
                icon: Icons.settings,
                text: "Settings",
              ),
            ],
            selectedIndex: currentPage,
            onTabChange: (index) {
              setState(() {
                currentPage = index;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
        onWillPop: () async {
          return false;
        });
  }

  Map<String, WidgetBuilder> _routeBuilders(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return {
      '/': (context) {
        return [
          MainPage(),
          SettingsPage()
        ].elementAt(index);
      },
    };
  }

  Widget buildOffstatgeNavigator(int index, GlobalKey key) {
    var routeBuilders = _routeBuilders(context, index);

    return Offstage(
      offstage: currentPage != index,
      child: WillPopScope(
          child: Navigator(
            key: key,
            onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
              return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    routeBuilders[routeSettings.name]!(context),
              );
            },
          ),
          onWillPop: () async {
            return !(await key.currentState!.maybePop());
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

2. I have a button in the MainPage widget which further routes to another page. After I press the back button on this page, I expect the app to navigate me back to the MainPage. Instead, this back press is handled by the tab navigator and navigates me back to my phone's home screen.
   What can I do to solve these problems?

Comment: did u find a solution

Comment: To the 2nd problem, yes. I still haven't figured out how to solve the 1st one.